# Using Ubuntu server 20.04 as router - no internet on clients

Tags: networking, server, iptables, router

I'm trying to setup an Ubuntu box as a small router. It has two NICs and is connected to a switch. I'm following this guide: https://medium.com/@exesse/how-to-make-a-simple-router-gateway-from-ubuntu-server-18-04-lts-fd40b7bfec9

The server is connected to the internet and the DHCP server works fine - IP addresses are attributed to client machines (both Windows and Ubuntu) and I'm able to SSH into the server. However, the clients have no internet access. Let me post below some information.

**Interfaces:**

```
imarques@felix-cs:~$ ip -c a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:08:a1:97:21:2e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.215.95/24 brd 192.168.215.255 scope global dynamic enp4s2
       valid_lft 63882sec preferred_lft 63882sec
    inet6 fe80::208:a1ff:fe97:212e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:18:8b:16:a3:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.42.0.1/24 brd 10.42.0.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::218:8bff:fe16:a341/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**enp4s2** is the internet connection on the server and **enp2s0** is NIC that is connected to the switch and supposed to share the internet access to the clients.

**Netplan:**

```
imarques@felix-cs:~$ cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp4s2:
      dhcp4: yes
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.42.0.1/24]
```

**DCHP server:**

```
imarques@felix-cs:~$ cat /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server 
# Defaults for isc-dhcp-server (sourced by /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server)

# Path to dhcpd's config file (default: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf).
#DHCPDv4_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
#DHCPDv6_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd6.conf

# Path to dhcpd's PID file (default: /var/run/dhcpd.pid).
#DHCPDv4_PID=/var/run/dhcpd.pid
#DHCPDv6_PID=/var/run/dhcpd6.pid

# Additional options to start dhcpd with.
#   Don't use options -cf or -pf here; use DHCPD_CONF/ DHCPD_PID instead
#OPTIONS=""

# On what interfaces should the DHCP server (dhcpd) serve DHCP requests?
#   Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. "eth0 eth1".
INTERFACESv4="enp2s0"
INTERFACESv6=""

imarques@felix-cs:~$ cat /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
default-lease-time 86400;
max-lease-time 86400;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 10.42.0.255;
authorative;
subnet 10.42.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 range 10.42.0.20 10.42.0.100;
  option routers 10.42.0.1;
  option domain-name-servers 10.42.0.1;
    }
```

**IP forward:**

```
imarques@felix-cs:~$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

**IPtables rules:**

```
imarques@felix-cs:~$ cat /etc/iptables/rules.v4 
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Fri Nov 27 16:43:56 2020
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [195:13486]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [166:13592]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Nov 27 16:43:56 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Fri Nov 27 16:43:56 2020
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [21:2246]
:INPUT ACCEPT [9:1593]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Nov 27 16:43:56 2020
```

This has been like this for some days and I've looked around but all instructions seemed similar. Any ideas?

######################################################

edits (2020/12/15) and thanks to Doug Smythies:

**pinging from the server:**

```
imarques@felix-cs:~$ ping -c 4 www.sapo.pt
PING www.sapo.pt (213.13.146.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sapo.pt (213.13.146.142): icmp_seq=1 ttl=242 time=14.9 ms
64 bytes from sapo.pt (213.13.146.142): icmp_seq=2 ttl=242 time=12.9 ms
64 bytes from sapo.pt (213.13.146.142): icmp_seq=3 ttl=242 time=13.5 ms
64 bytes from sapo.pt (213.13.146.142): icmp_seq=4 ttl=242 time=13.0 ms

--- www.sapo.pt ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.855/13.578/14.927/0.813 ms

imarques@felix-cs:~$ ping -c 4 213.13.146.142
PING 213.13.146.142 (213.13.146.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 213.13.146.142: icmp_seq=1 ttl=242 time=13.4 ms
64 bytes from 213.13.146.142: icmp_seq=2 ttl=242 time=12.9 ms
64 bytes from 213.13.146.142: icmp_seq=3 ttl=242 time=12.9 ms
64 bytes from 213.13.146.142: icmp_seq=4 ttl=242 time=12.9 ms

--- 213.13.146.142 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.890/13.018/13.369/0.203 ms
```

**pinging from the client:**

```
imarques@client07:~$ ping -c 4 www.sapo.pt
ping: www.sapo.pt: Name or service not known

imarques@client07:~$ ping -c 4 213.13.146.142
PING 213.13.146.142 (213.13.146.142) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 213.13.146.142 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3057ms
```

**tcpdump** generates lot of output... I tried it while pinging the same IP from the client:

```
imarques@felix-cs:~$ sudo tcpdump -i enp4s2 | grep 10.42
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp4s2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
10:40:31.865636 IP 10.42.0.94 > sapo.pt: ICMP echo request, id 21362, seq 1, length 64
10:40:32.866201 IP 10.42.0.94 > sapo.pt: ICMP echo request, id 21362, seq 2, length 64
10:40:33.890199 IP 10.42.0.94 > sapo.pt: ICMP echo request, id 21362, seq 3, length 64
10:40:34.914199 IP 10.42.0.94 > sapo.pt: ICMP echo request, id 21362, seq 4, length 64
10:40:35.938194 IP 10.42.0.94 > sapo.pt: ICMP echo request, id 21362, seq 5, length 64
10:40:36.962194 IP 10.42.0.94 > sapo.pt: ICMP echo request, id 21362, seq 6, length 64
10:40:37.986188 IP 10.42.0.94 > sapo.pt: ICMP echo request, id 21362, seq 7, length 64
10:40:39.010196 IP 10.42.0.94 > sapo.pt: ICMP echo request, id 21362, seq 8, length 64
10:40:40.034196 IP 10.42.0.94 > sapo.pt: ICMP echo request, id 21362, seq 9, length 64
10:40:41.058192 IP 10.42.0.94 > sapo.pt: ICMP echo request, id 21362, seq 10, length 64
```

**iptables** info:

```
imarques@felix-cs:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -xnvL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 15969 packets, 1077775 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 15501 packets, 1031506 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1166 packets, 112828 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1269 packets, 118672 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       2      120 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      enp2s0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0        
       
imarques@felix-cs:~$ sudo iptables -xnvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 89829 packets, 4283290 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 1774 packets, 289508 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 159993 packets, 37244234 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I'm sorry, but I don't know how to check the MASQUERADE packet counter...

###########################################################################

second edit (2020/12/15).
rebooted the server and the client.

while pinging 213.13.146.142 from the client (10.42.0.94):

```
imarques@felix-cs:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -xnvL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2375 packets, 155967 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2292 packets, 150880 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 25 packets, 1564 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 50 packets, 3008 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       1       60 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      enp2s0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
imarques@felix-cs:~$ sudo tcpdump -tttt -n -vvv -i  enp2s0 host 213.13.146.142
tcpdump: listening on enp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
2020-12-15 16:02:07.170117 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 13547, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.42.0.94 > 213.13.146.142: ICMP echo request, id 1625, seq 1, length 64
2020-12-15 16:02:08.176165 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 13620, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.42.0.94 > 213.13.146.142: ICMP echo request, id 1625, seq 2, length 64
2020-12-15 16:02:09.200188 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 13856, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.42.0.94 > 213.13.146.142: ICMP echo request, id 1625, seq 3, length 64
2020-12-15 16:02:10.224214 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 13971, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.42.0.94 > 213.13.146.142: ICMP echo request, id 1625, seq 4, length 64
2020-12-15 16:02:11.248242 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 14165, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.42.0.94 > 213.13.146.142: ICMP echo request, id 1625, seq 5, length 64
2020-12-15 16:02:12.272264 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 14275, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.42.0.94 > 213.13.146.142: ICMP echo request, id 1625, seq 6, length 64
2020-12-15 16:02:13.296286 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 14530, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.42.0.94 > 213.13.146.142: ICMP echo request, id 1625, seq 7, length 64
2020-12-15 16:02:14.320323 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 14641, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.42.0.94 > 213.13.146.142: ICMP echo request, id 1625, seq 8, length 64
2020-12-15 16:02:15.344341 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 14737, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.42.0.94 > 213.13.146.142: ICMP echo request, id 1625, seq 9, length 64
2020-12-15 16:02:16.368366 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 14801, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.42.0.94 > 213.13.146.142: ICMP echo request, id 1625, seq 10, length 64
^C
10 packets captured
10 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
imarques@felix-cs:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -xnvL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 3198 packets, 210191 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 3081 packets, 203146 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 25 packets, 1564 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 58 packets, 3456 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       1       60 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      enp2s0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Please edit your question adding the output for `sudo iptables -t nat -xnvL`. Then we can observe the packet counters for your MASQUERADE command. Next, suggest two tcpdump sessions, one monitoring each network interface, checking send and return path. Might as well also do `sudo iptables -xnvL` so we can see all the counters. Check the MASQUERADE packet counter before and after a client attempts internet stuff (say, `ping 8.8.8.8`)

Comment: Please clarify: your clients do not have internet access OR they do not have DNS access? (the ping test will tell the answer) Do you have a DNS at 10.42.0.1,as you are telling your dhcp clients?

Comment: I've edited the post with some of the requested info. many thanks!

Comment: O.K. so we know the client is sending the packets and they get to your server. You need to simultaneously run another tcpdump session in another terminal looking at the outgoing interface: `sudo tcpdump -tttt -n -vvv -i  enp2s0 host 213.13.146.142` to see if: the packets leave the server (outgoing either O.K., or the issue is in the send path); return (proves the issue is in the return path). Your MASQUERADE packet counter was 2.

Comment: Your MASQUERADE packet counter should increment by 1 per ping.

Comment: no visible increment on MASQUERADE  ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your NAT (Network Address Translation) rule is backwards.
This:

```
-A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

should be:

```
-A POSTROUTING -o enp4s2 -j MASQUERADE
```

By the way, I assume your current iptables rule set is just the beginning and eventually you will add some firewall type stuff. Actually, since there must be another router between your server and the actual internet, it is much less important.

Comment: okay, I can now ping IP addresses from the client.

imarques@client07:~$ ping -c 10 213.13.146.142
PING 213.13.146.142 (213.13.146.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 213.13.146.142: icmp_seq=1 ttl=241 time=13.1 ms
64 bytes from 213.13.146.142: icmp_seq=2 ttl=241 time=12.9 ms
^C
--- 213.13.146.142 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.968/13.064/13.161/0.149 ms
imarques@client07:~$ ping -c 10 www.sapo.pt
ping: www.sapo.pt: Name or service not known


I guess i'm still missing a DNS server?

Comment: well is your server a DNS? Your DHCP server is telling your clients that it is. If is not a DNS then you need to update your DHCP config to point to a real DNS. as a test, try the google DNS at 8.8.8.8

Comment: added the DNS to /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf. it is finally working. thank you so much!